# Error in R: replacement has ... rows, data has ....rows

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

```
df <- data.frame(values = c(2.5, 12, 4.8, 56, 78),
samples = c('45fe.K2', '59ji.K2', '59rc.K1', '45hi.K1', '96hu.K1'))

df$group <- NA
df$group <- apply(df,1,function(x)
{ifelse(grepl('K2',df$samples) == TRUE,paste('K2'),paste('K1'))})

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "PANEL", value = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L,  : 
 replacement has ... rows, data has ....rows
```

I am trying to do a boxplot with `df` but the problem is that whenever I try to do something that includes`df$group` the error occurs. What can I do about that? As mentioned in similar posts, I firstly made a new empty column that is filled in the next step. But the error occured nontheless. Can I work around somehow?

That question is related to a previous one, that was concerning about the boxplot [Grouped boxplot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63905273/grouped-boxplot-in-r/63906062?noredirect=1#comment113006882_63906062)

Comment: To make your code work, try `apply(df, 1, function(x){ ifelse(grepl('K2', x[2]), "K2", "K1") })`, although we don't write the code like this because `grepl` and `ifelse` are vectorised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grepl` and `ifelse` are vectorised so you don't need `apply` here :

```
df$group <- ifelse(grepl('K2', df$samples), 'K2', 'K1')
```

Without `ifelse` :

```
df$group <- paste0('K', as.integer(grepl('K2', df$samples)) + 1)
#Or extract K1, K2 value from the string
df$group <- sub('.*(K\\d+).*', '\\1', df$samples)
```